# fetch all places (lists/libraries/items) where permissions are given to 'Everyone' group

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, csom, everyone

I am working on office 365 SharePoint site.

I want to fetch all lists/libraries/items where permissions are given to **Everyone** group across SharePoint site using CSOM.

```
    Web web = context.Web;
var Lists = context.Web.Lists;
context.Load(Lists);
context.ExecuteQuery();
foreach (var List in Lists)
{
    context.Load(List.RoleAssignments);
    context.ExecuteQuery();
    foreach (var RoleAssignment in List.RoleAssignments)
    {
        context.Load(RoleAssignment.Member);
        context.ExecuteQuery();
        var EveryoneexceptexternalUsers = " c:0-.f|rolemanager|spo-grid-all-users/526bf739-e2f7-4c87-a8ce-0737198cc796";
        PrincipalType SharePointGroup = default(PrincipalType);
        if (RoleAssignment.Member.PrincipalType == SharePointGroup && RoleAssignment.Member.LoginName == EveryoneexceptexternalUsers) {
            Console.WriteLine(List.Title, "has Everyone Group");

        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Everyone group is not present in the List");
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't run the PowerShell script. Instead of PowerShell converted that into csom. I have posted my code here. I have added everyone group in a list. when I run the code it is not fetching the list name instead of that it is executing else condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 Web web = context.Web;
                var Lists = context.Web.Lists;
                context.Load(Lists);
                context.ExecuteQuery();
                foreach (var List in Lists)
                {
                    context.Load(List.RoleAssignments);
                    context.ExecuteQuery();
                    Console.WriteLine(List.Title);
                    if (List.Title.StartsWith("Employee"))
                    {
                        foreach (var RoleAssignment in List.RoleAssignments)
                        {
                            context.Load(RoleAssignment.Member, r => r.LoginName, r => r.PrincipalType);
                            context.ExecuteQuery();
                            var EveryoneexceptexternalUsers = "c:0-.f|rolemanager|spo-grid-all-users/526bf739-e2f7-4c87-a8ce-0737198cc796";
                            //PrincipalType SharePointGroup = default(PrincipalType);
                            if (RoleAssignment.Member.LoginName == EveryoneexceptexternalUsers)//RoleAssignment.Member.PrincipalType == SharePointGroup && 
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine(List.Title, "has Everyone Group");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Everyone group is not present in the List");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
```

Comment: I have done small changes now it is working

Comment: Note that neither this nor the other answers here address your requirement to check permissions on list _items_ that may have unique permissions

Answer (score 0):

To achieve your requirement, there is a PowerShell script for your reference.

```
    #Load SharePoint CSOM Assemblies
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"

Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"
#Variables for Processing
$SiteUrl = "https://tenantname.sharepoint.com/sites/sitename"
$UserName="username"
$Password ="password"

#Setup Credentials to connect

$Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($UserName,(ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force))


    $Context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteUrl) 

    $Context.Credentials = $credentials


    #sharepoint online powershell get all lists

    $Lists = $Context.web.Lists

    $Context.Load($Lists)

    $Context.ExecuteQuery()



    #Iterate through each list in a site   

    ForEach($List in $Lists)
    {

        $Context.Load($List.RoleAssignments)
        $Context.ExecuteQuery()
        Foreach($RoleAssignment in $List.RoleAssignments)
        { 
               $Context.Load($RoleAssignment.Member)

               $Context.executeQuery()

               If($RoleAssignment.Member.PrincipalType -eq "SharePointGroup" -And $RoleAssignment.Member.LoginName -eq "Everyone"){

                    Write-host $List.Title "has Everyone Group"

                } 

        }




    }
```

More reference:

[SharePoint Online: Site Collection Permissions Report using PowerShell.](http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2018/09/sharepoint-online-site-collection-permission-report-using-powershell.html)

Comment: But still not able to fetch.

Comment: did you encounter the error when running the powershell script?

Comment: I didn't run the PowerShell script. Instead of PowerShell converted that into csom. I have posted my code here. I have added everyone group in a list. when I run the code it is not fetching the list name instead of that it is executing else condition.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer different approach, especially in large environments. Instead of iterating all the content, which might take days and weeks for a good mature tenant, I use search:

1. You'd need to register an account and do not provide to this account any permissions to SharePoint sites
2. You'd search content on behalf of this account (I'd recommend [search with Graph API][1]). Everything you'd find would be content shared with everyone.

```
# Search
# MS Graph Search API url (beta or v1.0):
$apiUrl = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/search/query"
$apiUrl = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/search/query"

# specify where to search - entity types
$entityTypes = "['driveItem','listItem','list','drive','site']"

# query all tenant content 
$query = "*"

# query specific site 
$query = "* site:https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/mysite"

# build a simple request body
$body = @"
{ 
  "requests": [
    {
      "entityTypes": $entityTypes,
      "query": {
        "queryString": "$query"
      }
    }
  ]
}
"@

# call Graph API:
$res = Invoke-RestMethod -Headers $Headers -Uri $apiUrl -Body $Body -Method Post -ContentType 'application/json'

# explore returned object
$res.value[0].hitsContainers[0].hits

Here is the article on "[How to Find Content Shared with Everyone in SharePoint and Teams][2]" and video "[Discover SharePoint content shared with everyone in Microsoft 365][3]".
 


  [1]: https://vladilen.com/microsoft-365/search-m-365-content-programmatically/
  [2]: https://vladilen.com/software/microsoft-365/find-sites-shared-with-everyone-in-spo/
  [3]: https://youtu.be/3v_TxXd6ZWc?si=FDy7NIK5yoPz6ttz
```